# Conditional filtering where the filter variable and its related data points change column in each row

Tags: r, tidyverse

I’ve been doing a project with sports data and I’ve come to a problem with the structure of the data, which is making it difficult to filter correctly.
The data is based on a sport where each match has two teams playing multiple rounds. Each line of data in the set is a match and looks something like this:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~TeamX, ~TeamY, ~TeamXScore, ~TeamYScore, ~TeamXOutcome, ~TeamYOutcome,
  "Team 1", "Team 2", 10, 11, 0, 1,
  "Team 1", "Team 3", 11, 10, 1, 0, 
  "Team 4", "Team 1", 11, 10, 1, 0, 
  "Team 5", "Team 1", 10, 11, 0, 1
)
```

Each row contains identifying information for Team X and Team Y, as well as the scores and outcomes for each team.

I’m now at the stage where I’ve created a number of match-based stats that are assigned to both Team X and Team Y, but to get the full use of them I need to filter the data to only show stats for a specific team. With the data in the format outlined above this requires some kind of conditional filtering or trimming of the data based on whether the team we want to filter is listed as Team X or Team Y in each row of the data set. If a filter was applied to the above example data for “Team 1” the output would look something like this:

```
df2 <- tribble(
  ~Team, ~Score, ~Outcome,
  "Team 1", 10, 0,
  "Team 1", 11, 1,
  "Team 1", 10, 0, 
  "Team 1", 11, 1
)
```

Any suggestions about how to implement something like this would be much appreciated. I understand the data would be easier to work with in a different format but I'd like to see if this route is possible before considering re-structuring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define some kind of `select_filter` function which basically filters, selects and binds those rows together. The nice thing about this function is, that you can use it on similar problems.  It's rather hacky, but its working.
Some important notes:

- The columns you finally want to select need to contain one of the
  names of the identifying columns (here `TeamX` and `TeamY`).
- The `.cond` argument needs to be in formula style `~` with `.x` as a
  placeholder for the identifying columns.
- You must name the ellipsis argument (`...`) to specify the name of
  your new identifying column which will also be the stem of all other
  columns in the returned `data.frame`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

df <- tribble(
  ~TeamX, ~TeamY, ~TeamXScore, ~TeamYScore, ~TeamXOutcome, ~TeamYOutcome,
  "Team 1", "Team 2", 10, 11, 0, 1,
  "Team 1", "Team 3", 11, 10, 1, 0, 
  "Team 4", "Team 1", 11, 10, 1, 0, 
  "Team 5", "Team 1", 10, 11, 0, 1
)

select_filter <- function(df, .cond, ...) {
  
  cond <- rlang::enexpr(.cond)[[2]]
  exp <- enexprs(...)
  cols <- map(as.list(exp[[1]][-1]), as.name)
  name <- names(exp)
  
  eval_tidy(bquote(map_dfr(cols, ~
                       df %>%
                         filter(!! .(cond)) %>%
                         select(contains(as.character(.x))) %>%
                         rename_with(function(y) gsub(as.character(.x), name, y)) 
                         )
                   )
            )
  
}

select_filter(df, ~ .x  == "Team 1", Team = c("TeamX", "TeamY"))

#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   Team   TeamScore TeamOutcome
#>   <chr>      <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1 Team 1        10           0
#> 2 Team 1        11           1
#> 3 Team 1        10           0
#> 4 Team 1        11           1

select_filter(df, ~ .x  %in% c("Team 1", "Team 2", "Team 3"), id = c("TeamX", "TeamY"))

#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   id     idScore idOutcome
#>   <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 Team 1      10         0
#> 2 Team 1      11         1
#> 3 Team 2      11         1
#> 4 Team 3      10         0
#> 5 Team 1      10         0
#> 6 Team 1      11         1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

---

You could do it easily without this kind of function and just use `bind_rows` and `rename`.

```r
df %>% 
  select(contains("X")) %>% 
  bind_rows({df %>% 
              select(contains("Y")) %>% 
              rename_with(~ gsub("Y", "X", .x))
    }) %>% 
  rename(Team = "TeamX") %>% 
  rename_with(~ gsub("TeamX", "", .x)) %>% 
  filter(Team == "Team 1")
```

---

Alternative approach 2 using `pivot_longer` and `case_when`

```r
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(TeamX, TeamY),
               values_to = "Team") %>% 
    mutate(Score = case_when(
                    name == "TeamX" ~ TeamXScore,
                    name == "TeamY" ~ TeamYScore,
                    T ~ NaN),
           Outcome = case_when(
             name == "TeamX" ~ TeamXOutcome,
             name == "TeamY" ~ TeamYOutcome,
             T ~ NaN)
      ) %>% 
  select(Team, Score, Outcome) %>% 
  filter(Team == "Team 1")
```

Comment: These two approaches are much appreciated and both give the desired outcome. Thanks for your help Tim

Comment: Hi Tim, really chuffed with these solutions. I'm amazed by how smoothly the function solution works. Cheers

Comment: @jhclarkk: Thanks! The function is still pretty rough and has a lot of edge cases, but I kinda like it too. If you think that the three approaches answer your question, it would be great if you could accept the answer.